# Is it possible to count no. of rows belonging to a partition if I use clustering columns

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

updated after comment from Jim.

I have a database with schema

```
field1 //partition key
field2 //clustering column
field3
```

I suppose `Cassandra` will calculate hash on field1, decide in which node this data entry will go into and will store it there. As I am using clustering column, for 2 data entries with same value of `field1` but different values of `field2`, the data will be stored as two rows.

```
field1, field2.1, field3
field1, field2.2, field3
```

Is it possible to create a query which would return value `2` (count of rows) as there are two rows belonging to partition key `field1`?

Comment: So I think you need some clarification from your description. Your clustering columns must be part of your primary key. You can't have "field 1" be the primary key and have "field 2" be a clustering column. You CAN have "field 1, field 2" as the primary key with field 2 being a clustering column and field 1 being the partition key. Is that what you meant? Or are you not fully understanding the cassandra model?

Comment: yes, that is what i meant. sorry, wasn't clear

Comment: Then the count(*) for a particular partition would definitely show 2 rows. Not sure that answers your question or not.

Comment: Thanks Jim. `count` works. As you started the discussion, I'll be happy to accept your answer if you provide one.

Comment: Would you know what would be the equivalent if I am using a java driver? I know that if I run a query, I get a `ResultSet`. Would the result set contain one column `count` with value `2`?

Comment: If you run "count(*)", and it actually finishes without timing out, result set will return the value 2 as it's a single row of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a

> select count(*) from table where field1 = “x” ;

You should get two in case of the example shown in your question